# C# Conversion failed when converting date and /or time from character string

Tags: sql, datetime

I have a txt file containing text like this:

```
DBPATH:  redirect.nsf
DBTITLE:  Redirect AP
DATETIME:  09.03.2015 09:44:21 AM
READS:  1
Adds:  0
```

when I get the 09.03.2015 09:44:21 AM and insert it into database
The system returns Conversion failed when converting date and /or time from character string.

I know it is about to convert it into Datetime format.

But Since I have used a string array (String [] word) to contain all info including the date in string array word[4]

I would like to know how to convert 09.03.2015 09:44:21 AM into datetime format into database, thanks!

Comment: What is 09? month or day?

Comment: 09.03.2015 dd.mm.yyyy

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it into datetime datatype before saving into DB.You need to use this function and you can store to your table. This will return you a datetime and you can save it in your database.

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '09.03.2015 09:44:21 AM', 102)
```

Comment: how to implement it in the C# program

Comment: @Kevin Please edit that information into the question. You didn't tag c# and you didn't write anything about how you are inserting the datetime into the database. Basically, from c# you should be sending an instance of the DateTime struct to the database, not a string. Also, you might want to add a tag for the rdbms you are using.